# changes in keras syntax?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have a script that worked just fine in a previous version of keras. Running the script on distribution 0.3.2, I get all sort of error messages. Below you will find some lines of the script:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dropout(self.dropx[0]))
model.add(Dense(nb_features, self.nb_neuronx[0], init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(PReLU((self.nb_neuronx[0],)))
model.add(BatchNormalization((self.nb_neuronx[0],)))
model.add(Dropout(self.dropx[1]))

model.add(Dense(self.nb_neuronx[0], self.nb_neuronx[1], init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(PReLU((self.nb_neuronx[1],)))
model.add(BatchNormalization((self.nb_neuronx[1],)))
model.add(Dropout(self.dropx[2]))
```

Some of the errors that I get are:

```
Exception: Layer is not connected. Did you forget to set "input_shape"?
```

Is there any 'from-to' type of document to go through and be in an easier position to update older keras scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an input dimension because it's the only dimension which cannot be inferred from previous layers.